# Button turn green for 2 seconds?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a button turn Green temporarily for 2 seconds, showing that the text was copied to the clipboard, and then go back to the way it was before. How can I do it?

Code:

```
@State private var copied = false
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

Other code...

```
Button(action: {
    UIPasteboard.general.setValue("Test", forPasteboardType: kUTTypePlainText as String)
    copied = true
                        
}) {
    copied ?
        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
            .font(.system(size: 21, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(8)
            .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(5)
                        :
        Image(systemName: "envelope.fill")
            .font(.system(size: 21, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(8)
            .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(5)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `timer`, you should use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` for delays. Like this:

```
Button(action: {
    UIPasteboard.general.setValue("Test", forPasteboardType: kUTTypePlainText as String)
    copied = true

    /// delay 2 seconds
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        copied = false
    }
})
```

Result:

[image: Click to turn green and back to blue after 2 seconds]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's all I needed!